# Confusion in wp-config.php editing

Tags: wordpress, phpmyadmin, hosting

actually I am in trouble with hosting our company website! the website perfectly working in local host but not working in hosted server..
I need clarification that when i have edited the wp_config.php, I put like this

```
       define('DB_NAME', 'my_db');

           /** MySQL database username */
               define('DB_USER', 'my_user');

           /** MySQL database password */
               define('DB_PASSWORD', 'my_pswd');

           /** MySQL hostname */
               define('DB_HOST', '10.31.88.141'); // IP adress of the server

           /** TR88575 */
               define('FTP_HOST', 'my_ftp');

           /** Database Charset to use in creating database tables. */
               define('DB_CHARSET', 'utf8');

           /** The Database Collate type. Don't change this if in doubt. */
               define('DB_COLLATE', '');
```

then I have exported my local database and opened it with text editor and replace all  **localhost/myfolder/ to  www.myurl.com/myfolder/**

then create a new database in host cpanel with same name of my local database and imported successfully.
 when login, only front page with some links no images no slider .. no navigation ???

my question  is should I replace local host to 10.31.88.141 in the exported database ? instead of my site url ?

Please give me suggestion to 1 **Editing wp-config ?**
                             2 **Editing exported local .sql file(database) with     text editor**
please please please help  :( :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to change two parameter in the table `wp_options` in your database.

> home

and

> siteurl

for example:

Now this to parameter looks something like that:

```
home -> localhost

siteurl -> localhost
```

Only change this to (e.g.)

```
home -> http://example.com/

siteurl -> http://example.com/
```

Here are some tutorials if you move a wordpress installation to another domain/server:

https://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress

http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2013/04/moving-wordpress-website/

Comment: That means  no need to edit the exported database file? like localhost/myfolder to www.mysite.com/myfolder???? thanks

Comment: If you move your localhost test wordpress to a live server you only have to change the database and the wp-config.php

Comment: "have to change the database and the wp-config.php" means what? please clear. My doubt is should I omit  opening the exported database in text editor and replacing all "localhost" to site url ? part???

Comment: No... You import your exported database into the new database and change the two parameters.

Comment: now a small change happen that is company logo is coming... and all other like menu slider etc are just like list of links and misplaced.no idea where to check and edit ..  :(

Comment: Thats is because you change a wrong home and siteurl in the database.

Answer (score 0):

There are still a lot of references of localhost in your DB I guess (because WP puts a lot of them hard in the DB). Try exporting the database with [WP Migrate DB](https://nl.wordpress.org/plugins/wp-migrate-db/) to rewrite all those entries. Then your images will work again.